# Delete files by condition and delete empty folders afterwards

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with the following content:

```
projects
└───folder1
│   │   file001.txt
│   │   file002.txt
│   │   ...
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file001.txt
│       │   file002.txt
│       │   ...
│   
└───folder2
│   │   file001.txt
│   │   file002.txt
│   │   ...
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file001.txt
│       │   file002.txt
│       │   ...
│......................
```

I currently have the following script but it doesn't do everything I need. It only deletes the files, but I want it to also delete the subfolders that are inside the folders recursively as long as they are not excluded.
This is the script I have:

```
param(
[string] $dir = "C:\projects",
[string] $logfile = "C:\logs\projects.log", 
[string] $days = "30")

$error.clear()
try
{
    # set to midnight
    $refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).Date

    # an array of folder names to exclude
    $excludeFolders = 'folder1', 'folder4', 'folder8'

    # create a regex of the folders to exclude
    # each folder will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
    $notThese = ($excludeFolders | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch $notThese -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | 
    Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>$logfile

}

catch {
    Write-Error  $_
}

if (!$error) {
    Write-Host  'Data deleted for files which are older than' $days 'Days'
}
```

And the result to be achieved would be the following:

```
projects
└───folder1
│   │   file001.txt
│   │   file002.txt
│   │   ...
│   │
│   └───subfolder1
│       │   file001.txt
│       │   file002.txt
│       │   ...
│   
└───folder2
│......................
```

Comment: So you basically want to delete empty folders after you have deleted the files?

Comment: That is, I want to delete the empty directories of the non-excluded ones, although I have seen that they are not completely empty because there is a thumb.db file in all of them that is not deleted.

Comment: `thumb.db` can't be deleted while Windows Explorer is holding on to them. You might have to kill/restart Explorer first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to efficiently delete empty directories in a 2nd pass:

```sh
$parentDirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch $notThese -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Remove-Item $_ -Force -Verbose
        $_.DirectoryName  # gets captured into $parentDirs
    } 4>$logfile   # most efficient at the end of the pipeline

$parentDirs |
    # Get unique parent dirs, sorted by length descending (to process nested dirs first)
    Sort-Object -Unique | Sort-Object Length -Descending |
    # Get only empty dirs
    Where-Object { -not ( Get-ChildItem $_ | Select-Object -First 1 ) } |
    # Delete empty directory
    Remove-Item -Verbose 4>>$logfile
```

- `$_.DirectoryName` is *implicit* output. PowerShell captures it into `$parentDirs`, automatically creating an array if there are more than one directories.
- Of course `$parentDirs` may contain duplicates, which are removed using `Sort-Object -Unique`.
- The unique directories are sorted by length (descending) so we delete the most deeply nested directories first. By deleting a nested directory, a parent directory may become empty, so it can be deleted as well.
- To efficiently check for empty directories, we use `Select-Object -First 1` which ends enumeration after the first of any children has been found. The condition evaluates to `$true` if `Get-ChildItem` doesn't output anything.